# Grouping columns in pivot query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's consider such query:

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
 SELECT
 YEAR(OrderDate) [Year],
 MONTH(OrderDate) [Month],
 SubTotal
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
 ) TableDate
 PIVOT (
 SUM(SubTotal)
 FOR [Month] IN (
  [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]
 )
) PivotTable
```

It returns a table looking like this:

```
 year    1    2   3    4    5     6    ...    12  //MONTH
 2001   100  100 100  100  100   100         100
```

How can we group the columns and return a result in the form,for example:

```
    year     1-3  4-5  5-10 11-12  //Group the columns!
    2001     300  200  500   200
```

I need a T-SQL query to do this. I 've checked dynamic query execution but it also doesn't help much..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the subquery, first put your months in the right buckets, then perform a pivot on that table.

```
    SELECT *
     FROM (
     SELECT
     YEAR(OrderDate) [Year],
     CASE WHEN MONTH(OrderDate)<=3 THEN '1-3'
          WHEN MONTH(OrderDate)<=5 THEN '4-5',
          WHEN MONTH(OrderDate)<=10 THEN '6-10',
          ELSE '11-12' END [MonthRange]
     SubTotal
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
     ) TableDate
     PIVOT (
     SUM(SubTotal)
     FOR [MonthRange] IN (
      ['1-3'],['4-5'],['6-10'],['11-12']
     )
    ) PivotTable
```

Comment: +1 I like this better as it's more extensible (e.g. mine only works because it is SUM).

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the solution to my problem:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use PIVOT that much (and don't have enough info here to re-create your sample), but can't you just say instead of SELECT *:

```
SELECT [year], [1-3] = [1] + [2] + [3], [4-5] = [4] + [5], ...
FROM ( SELECT YEAR ...) TableDate
PIVOT ( SUM(SubTotal) FOR ...) PivotTable;
```

**EDIT**
Adding a simple working example for @t-clausen.dk:

```
CREATE TABLE #x([year] INT, [month] INT, total INT);

INSERT #x SELECT 2011,  1, 15
UNION ALL SELECT 2011,  2, 20
UNION ALL SELECT 2011,  2, 30
UNION ALL SELECT 2011,  3, 15
UNION ALL SELECT 2011,  4, 22
UNION ALL SELECT 2011,  5, 13
UNION ALL SELECT 2011,  6, 22
UNION ALL SELECT 2011,  7, 12
UNION ALL SELECT 2011,  8, 14
UNION ALL SELECT 2011,  9, 30
UNION ALL SELECT 2011, 10, 30
UNION ALL SELECT 2011, 11, 20
UNION ALL SELECT 2011, 12, 45;

SELECT 
    [year],
    [1-3]   =  [1] +  [2] + [3],
    [4-5]   =  [4] +  [5],
    [6-10]  =  [6] +  [7] + [8] + [9] + [10],
    [11-12] = [11] + [12]
FROM ( SELECT [year], [month], total FROM #x ) AS TableDate
PIVOT (
    SUM(total)
    FOR [month] IN 
    (
        [1], [2], [3], [4],
        [5], [6], [7], [8],
        [9],[10],[11],[12]
    )
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY [year];

DROP TABLE #x;
```

Comment: This looks really odd to me, how would this part work [1-3] = [1] + [2] + [3] ?

Comment: The column names [1], [2] etc. are part of the result set produced by the PIVOT. Did you try it?